# What is the protective part of a staircase handrail called?

Tags: terminology

Below the handrail of a staircase is some kind of gridwork to prevent people or objects from falling off the staircase into the space below. What is the term for this gridwork? - perhaps "handrail grating"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the handrail is not mounted on wall then it must be mounted on a guardrail with 42 inch height and no opening which would allow any ball greater then or equal to 4 inch pass through.

This is LA code.

Comment: Name? Does not answer the question.

Comment: 'guardrail' is the term I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The first and last are called newel posts and the intermediate ones are called spindles.

But whether these names apply to materials other than wood is a different question.